# Title rows and columns of matplotlib subplot layout (replacing subplots with titles)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Suppose I have a 3x3 array of 9 subplots of identical sizes. Is it possible to make a 4x4 figure and replace the top and left-most subplots with large titles?

I know it's theoretically possible to use some sort of text box, but those don't scale very well and require a lot of tweaking. Suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I was thinking of something similar to this except with proper graphs inside the array:
[image]

Comment: There might be a cleaner way, but you can fake this by just using `text` or `annotate` inside of the edge axes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me a job for [`GridSpec` or `subplot2grid`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Besides the above link, you can find some example and code [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html)

Comment: Thank you Francesco, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I need a row or column title system. The links you sent are for merging multiple subplots.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use large, rotated x and y labels to achieve something similar:

Pandas

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = DataFrame(randn(1000, 8), columns=['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6', 'Label7', 'Label8'])
    fig = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
    for axes in fig:
        for ax in axes:
            ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation='horizontal', ha='right', fontsize=16)
            ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)
            ax.set_yticklabels('')
            ax.set_xticklabels('')
    plt.gcf().set_facecolor('w')
```

[image]

Seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white")

df = DataFrame(randn(50, 6), columns=['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6'])
g = sns.PairGrid(df, diag_sharey=False, size=1.4)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_upper(plt.scatter)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=2)
for axes in g.axes:
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation='horizontal', ha='right', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_yticklabels('')
        ax.set_xticklabels('')
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
plt.gcf().set_facecolor('w')
```

[image]

Both examples are from their respective tutorials and then tweaked a little.